# How do I get an RSS feed to process with PHP?

Tags: php, rss, feed

All I'm finding is how to parse the content so far.  Parsing the content isn't a problem for me, I'm just not clear on how to GET the content!  If I have a bunch of XML files sitting in a folder, I can easily sift through them all and process them, I just don't know how to get them in the folder in the first place.

I could also crawl to the locations of the files and grab them that way, but all the feeds I'm finding seem to just be links to news stories and whatnot, and none of them are just XML.

I don't want to use any third party CMS like Drupal or Wordpress.  Sorry if this is a stupid question.  Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: I did the searching last night, and now I just searched again and in five seconds found a pure XML RSS feed on the news site I was looking on where I couldn't find one last night.  Rather than providing downloadable files, is this all that RSS feeds will typically be given as?  Browsable files/pages?

EDIT2: Yup, looks like that's the case.  Sorry everyone!  Well, hopefully those with similar questions will be helped.

EDIT3:  Well, since I made the thread now anyway, could anyone tell me if SimpleXML or a parse (say, Magpie) will be faster, processing-wise?  My assumption is SimpleXML is the way to go.

Comment: xml with cdata sections (carrying html for instance) is actually *just* xml. rss is actually not *just* xml, but an application of xml.

Comment: What sort of file are you referring to? Stack overflow's [feed for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/15263177) is XML.

Comment: I think I'm about to feel really dumb, depending on the answer to my edit.  Sorry if I'm wasting everyone's time here.  I thought I would actually be given FILES that I would download onto my server, rather than simply browsing to the given location and grabbing the text that way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available for reading but I like using ttp://magpierss.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you want, but, will this work for you?

```
wget -q -O-  "http://www.tuxradar.com/rss"
```

I did that in Cygwin on a PC, but, it will work on Linux or in a Mac terminal.  You can also redirect the output to file if you want:

```
wget -q -O-  "http://www.tuxradar.com/rss" > tux.xml
```

Comment: Fetching the RSS is not the Problem here, he want to know how to read